# How to get Date format in Japanese in ABAP

Tags: abap

NW ABAP 7.0
in SU01 You can set a users date format to Japanese  . Example Format 7

[image]

In code this works when run by the user.

```
" user date format set to JAPANESE   DATFM 7  
DATA: l_char TYPE text240, l_char1 TYPE c.
write sy-datum to l_char.
l_char1 = l_char(1).  " THIS WORKS
```

However we need to get this from a user that doesnt and cannot have this date format set.

```
write someDate to l_char 'YYYY.MM.DD'  is possible.
   But the format for Japanese is not available.

function CONVERT_DATE_TO_EXTERNAL
only works for the logged in users format.


Is there a functional that can delivery the japanese date string ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the following solution?

```
REPORT YYY.

WRITE |{ sy-datlo COUNTRY = 'JP ' }|.
```

Comment: Depends on the country setting. Previously I checked 3 systems, all of them had '5' as setting which is not the japanese format.

Comment: This works if T005x has the value 7,8 or 9 instead of the default 5 for Japan. However, we are restricted by the lowest version of customers. Currently we still support 7.0 so I cant use this style of command yet. I like this solution most as it applies to one statement only.

Comment: You're right. I was sure, that this was already available in NW 700 but apparently was first introduced in NW 702.

Answer (score 1):

If the user date setting works, you can use, [set country](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapset_country.htm) command, I guess. Or you tried it already?

Comment: I did try it, but on reading the abap docu but JP did not have format 7,8 or 9. The default value was 5. After changing table T005x to datfm 7 it worked.